# Integrating a dynamical system until an algebraic condition is satisfied

Tags: ode, software, numerics

I have a model given by a system of differential equations

$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=f(y)$$

with $y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$  and $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. The system works as follows : integrate the ode's with initial values $(y_1^0,y_2^0,y_3^0)$ until $y_1$ reaches a certain value (say $y_1=0$), get the time $t_f$ when this happens and start again with the initial values  $(y_1^0 ,y_2^0, y_3(t_f))$. All this until some stopping condition is encountered.

My question is : what software can be used to simulate such a system? It would be preferable to be open source, but any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: I'd implement this in MATLAB using the ODE _events_ framework. Have a look at [odeset](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) and [event locations](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html). If you do not have MATLAB installed, try the open-source `octave` and its `odepkg` package. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056580/solve-odes-until-an-event-occurs-in-octave).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB's ODE solvers can use what are known as [Event functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) to achieve this. I also link [someone who posted a good quick example to show how to use it](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19910-event-function-for-ode-solver) that is close to your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try SUNDIAL suite from LLNL. See https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/main.html.